# claudia and API-Gateway: forbidden (/latest)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, claudiajs

I'm using Claudia to transform my node.js app into an AWS lambda function. The integration works fine and I can access the index of my serverless website at this address:
https://*******.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest
Now I have a login page and a link to go to the page. My problem is when I click on this link, the URL is:
https://*********.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/login
which only returns me a forbidden message because the real page is located at:
https://******.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/login
How can I get rid of the /latest OR how can I handle it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have a custom domain? If yes, you can use custom domain in api gateway to point to the latest version. If no, can you include the `/latest` as your base url?

Comment: @KendrickKesley I have a custom domain, now, how do I set the API Gateway to point to the latest version? For your second idea, I could but then my node.js won't work in local and it would be a nightmare to handle that ^^

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the custom domain page, you will see an `edit mapping` in your custom domain. Just enter / in the path and in the right, there will be a version section. point it to latest

Comment: @KendrickKesley no problem ^^ I'm not sure to understand what you want me to do? The custom domain page, it's Route53 right? Because I can't link my API from API Gateway (the one that Claudia created) to my domain (I don't even know if that's possible)

Comment: Ah they're different. the page you're looking for is in the API gateway page. There's a section called `Custom Domain Names` in the left bar. You can create your custom domain in there

Comment: @KendrickKesley Hi, sorry it took me so long to answer... So I created a Custom Domain Name with these options: Edge Optimized, ACM Certificate linked to the domain name that I bought, and / linked to latest of my lambda function. Now I'm not sure I understand what I did and I don't think it's working ^^'  I named my Custom Domain Name www.<<website>>.com, does this have any importance?